# Python Heatmap from percentages of two categories

Tags: python, pivot-table, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataset of consisting of two columns, each column is a category and each row represents a user. A user will have an Age range in one column and a category (A-E) in another column.

I want to find the percentage of users in each category for each age range.
for example:

```
18-25: A - 25%, B - 35%, C - 30%, D - 5%, E - 5%
26-40: A - 15%, B - 45%, C - 10%, D - 15%, E - 15%
```

with this information I would like to create a sort of heatmap where age ranges go down the side
and the categories go along the top. and the "heat" of each cell is just how high the percentage of that respective category/age range is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using pandas, numpy, and seaborn:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create summaryTable
ageGroups = np.array(["18-25","26-40"])
categories = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E'])
summaryTable = pd.DataFrame(index=ageGroups, columns=categories)

ageGroupsInts = np.array([18,25,26,40])

counter = 0
for i in range(0, ageGroupsInts.shape[0], 2):
    inAgeGroupI = df.loc[df.Age >= ageGroupsInts[i]].loc[df.Age <= ageGroupsInts[i+1]]
    numEntries = inAgeGroupI.shape[0]
    
    for j in range(categories.shape[0]):
        df_catJ = inAgeGroupI.loc[inAgeGroupI.Category == categories[j]]
        
        summaryTable.at[ageGroups[counter], categories[j]] = df_catJ.shape[0] / numEntries * 100
        
    counter += 1
        

# Create heatmap 
summaryTable_np = summaryTable.to_numpy().astype(float)
xLabels = categories
yLabels = ageGroups
seaborn.heatmap(summaryTable_np, annot=True, linewidths=.5, square=True, 
                xticklabels=xLabels, yticklabels=yLabels,
                vmin=np.amin(summaryTable_np), vmax=np.amax(summaryTable_np), cmap='Reds')
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
```

where `df` is a (nRows,2) size data frame with columns 'Age' and 'Category' and `summaryTable` is a dataframe with the age groups as rows and the A-E categories as columns.

Here is an example output heatmap: 
[image: heatmap]